# how do i get numbers of recursive calls from this code?

Tags: c++, recursion

```
using namespace std;
static int count = 0;
int f(int n, int& count)
{
    count++;
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) return n;
    else
        return f(n - 1, count) + f(n - 2, count);
}
int main()
{
    int n = 7;
    int count = 0;
    cout << f(n, count) << " " << count;
}
```

the output of count is 0 and i don't know why.
my intend is to know the numbers of the recursive call

the thing before << is C out. if i connect them together i can't post the thing

Comment: Why do you have both a global static count, *and* a parameter count?

Comment: looks like with `int count = 0;` in main you are redeclaring `count` instead of using the global static which you actually want. or, if `f` is meant to keep track via the parameter, pass its address instead.

Comment: You have *two* distinct `count` variables.

Comment: @JesperJuhl but the `static int count = 0;` is neither used in `f` (because it is shadowed by the parameter `count`) nor in `main` because it is shadowed there by `int count`. `count++;` refers to the parameter `count` and that one is a reference to the `int count` of the `main`.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> cout << f(n, count) << " " << count;
> ```

You would expect `fn(n, count)` to be evaluated first and then `count`, but if you're using a version of C++ earlier than C++17 then the order of evaluation is *unspecified*. `<<` isn't a [sequence point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point).  The compiler is free to evaluate either `count` first or `fn(n, count)`. Hence the output that you get, i.e. `count` is evaluated first.

What you could do is introduce a sequence point like this:

```
cout << f(n, count);  //semicolon is a sequence point
cout << " " << count;
```

and you should get the output you're expecting. Also there is no need for a static varaible at all as the `count` is passed by reference.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you don't need to use the `static int count=0` as you are passing the reference to the variable `count` declared in `main`, but still, it won't change the output. The following code works in gcc compiler. I feel corrected by a comment from another user that the problem might be with the C++ version.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int f(int n, int& count)
{
    count++;
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) return n;
    else
        return f(n - 1, count) + f(n - 2, count);
}
int main()
{
    int n = 7;
    int count = 0;
    cout<<f(n, count)<<" "<< count;
}
```

Comment: Did you test what gcc shows if `static int count=0` is present? Because no matter if `static int count=0` is present or not, it will show the same result. Wether it is `0` or not depends not on `static int count=0`  but the use c++ version.